Screen pushed above while open with bottom sheet appeared
I expected the open with bottom sheet comes over the screen without affect my flutter widget.

I tried resizeToAvoidBottomInset,
I tried SafeArea in the body of widget,
SinglechildScrollView also not helpful

But it will push the screen to the top side when the bottom sheet from Android comes in. This will happen If I use the Openfile package to open PDF file from the flutter the same option selection box will push my screen to the top
This is the sample code to reproduce the issue
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class TestWidget extends StatelessWidget{
  const TestWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("This is pushed up"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: IconButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            final Uri url = Uri(
              scheme: "tel",
              path: "phone_no"
            );
            await launchUrl(url);
          }, 
          icon: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.phone)
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Can you please share what you are expecting and what you have tried now?
